# Using goto to fall-through in switch when also switching on type in C#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, polymorphism, goto

EDIT: I would reformulate the question:
Is it at all possible to use switch statement in this way. It seems that on one hand it is allowed to have types as cases which may simplify the look of the code, but then if you want to achieve reuse by falling-through using go to statement then this is not possible. As it currently stands I'm more interested in the language construct than actually solving the problem which I can solve by repeating some code or moving to if else statements.
I know `goto` is bad in general, but it seems that it is at least acceptable as a way to simulate the fall-through mechanism in C without being error prone to by using/omitting `break`; by mistake

I would like to use `switch` statement in conjunction with switching over types, but i want to use fall-trough using `goto`

I would like to perform different actions depending on the type of the element in the list:
but I get error: `Use of unassigned local variable 'animal1'` Can I do it using switch on the object type or I need to compare strings or use if-else constructs?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace switch_type_experiments
{
    public class Animal
    {
        public void Eat()
        { }
    }

    public class Mammal : Animal
    {
        public void DoMammalStuff()
        { }
    }

    public class Dog : Mammal
    {
        public void Bark()
        {
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Animal> listOfAnimals = new();

            foreach (Animal animal in listOfAnimals)
            {
                switch (animal)
                {
                    case Dog animal1:

                        //do stuff only applicable for dog such as accessing 
                        // available only for dogs
                        animal1.Bark();
                        goto MammalLabel;

                    case Mammal animal1:
                    MammalLabel:
                        //do Mammal stuff
                        animal1.DoMammalStuff();
                        goto AnimalLabel;


                    case Animal animal1:
                    AnimalLabel:
                        animal1.Eat();
                        //do Animal stuff

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: generally, using `goto` is a _bad_ idea. you should not do it, unless you know exactly what you're doing and you _have_ to use it. could you elaborate _why_ you think goto is the best solution for your problem? (in your case, a series of `if` might be appropriate.)

Comment: Not quite sure if it's that but your error leads me to believe that you are jumping out of your scope of the variable of animal1. After all you are jumping (meaning you don't execute the stuff before) after the cast when you come from the dog case and therefore access to animal1 leads to the error.

Comment: I just want to fall-through from one case to another to avoid code repetition because my object and logic is a bit more complicated than the example. It well may be than I'm overcomplicating things. It just seems now that I just need to get rid of `animal1` and use `animal` and cast it using `as`. I think that I also misunderstood how switch with types work. Not sure now how useful the question is and will leave it to the community if it gets a lot of downvotes I'll delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding is correct then you can achieve the same with only 3 lines of code instead of `switch` and `goto` statements:

```
foreach (Animal animal in listOfAnimals)
{
    if (animal is Dog dog) dog.Bark();
    if (animal is Mammal mammal) mammal.DoMammalStuff();
    animal.Eat();
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1**: Use `switch` statement

In C# you can call `break`, `return`, `continue`, `throw` or `goto` to control the fall-through.

`goto` has a really special version where you can jump to a `case x` rather than a predefined `label x`. But there is one caveat: the `x` must be compile time constant.

So, if you stick to use `switch` statement then you can do one of the following:

```
int type = animal switch
{
    Dog dog => 3,
    Mammal mammal => 2,
    _ => 1
};

switch (type)
{
    case 3:
        (animal as Dog).Bark();
        goto case 2;
    case 2:
        (animal as Mammal).DoMammalStuff();
        goto case 1;
    case 1:
        animal.Eat();
        break;
}
```

OR

```
ImmutableDictionary<Type, int> mapping = new Dictionary<Type, int>
{
    { typeof(Dog), 3 },
    { typeof(Mammal), 2 }
}.ToImmutableDictionary();

int type = mapping.TryGetValue(animal.GetType(), out type) ? type : 1;

switch (type)
{
    case 3:
        (animal as Dog).Bark();
        goto case 2;
    case 2:
        (animal as Mammal).DoMammalStuff();
        goto case 1;
    case 1:
        animal.Eat();
        break;
}
```

Comment: alternatively: `(animal as Dog)?.Bark();` should work as well and is a bit more succinct

Comment: Yes, that could make the code even more concise.

Comment: I know that this is good concise solution thus +1, but now I'm actually more curious if something along the lines is at all possible in C#. I have added some details to the question

Comment: Let me think about that.

Comment: @PiotrGolacki I've extended my answer please check it

Comment: So there is no way that I can use type names as cases and still having fall-through mechanism for example using goto?

Comment: @PiotrGolacki according to my knowledge no.